# Ffmpeg 1 image and 1 Audio from separate directories into mp4 random selection

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ffmpeg, sh

I have a folder of images and a folder of audio, thanks to @Ljm Dullaart 's help, this script takes an image from the image directory, merges it with an audio from the audio directory and outputs an mp4 but what I would like to make it so it takes a random image and random audio and merges them together without doing it infinitely, consuming the pair. I'm at a loss as to how to achieve this in linux, I've been able to do it in windows batch.

This script currently requires the audio and image to have the same file name:

```
for file in "$jpgdir"/*.jpg ; do

base=$(basename "$file")
stripped=${base%.jpg}
aac="$aacdir/$stripped.aac"
jpg="$jpgdir/$stripped.jpg"
mp4="$mp4dir/$stripped.mp4"

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "$jpg" -i "$aac" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest "$mp4"
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Note that "folders" is a user term. On Linux, also on Unix/BSD, they are "directories" and not the same thing as the Windows-ism of "folders".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is how I would approach it using [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/):

```
parallel --progress --shuf --halt now,success=20 'ffmpeg -loop 1 -i {1} -i {2} -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest -b:a 192k -shortest "{1.}_{2.}.mp4"' ::: "$jpgdir"/*.jpg ::: "$aacdir/*.aac
```

The `--shuf` option will feed in the aac/jpg files randomly, the `--progress` option will let you know how quickly the jobs are finishing, and the `--halt now,success=20` option specifies how many jpg/aac combinations you want in total (change the '20' to however many you need).